# How to call different methods from single webservices class

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a following RESTful webservice, I have two methods for http get. One function signs in and other function signs out a user from an application. Following is the code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author Pointer
 */
@Path("generic")
public class GenericResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of GenericResource
     */
    public GenericResource() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of
     * com.ef.apps.xmpp.ws.GenericResource
     *
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String SignIn(@QueryParam("username") String username, @QueryParam("password") String password, @QueryParam("extension") String extension) {

        //TODO return proper representation object
        return "Credentials  " + username + " : " + password + " : " + extension;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String SignOut(@QueryParam("username") String username, @QueryParam("password") String password, @QueryParam("extension") String extension) {

        //TODO return proper representation object
        return "Credentials  " + username + " : " + password + " : " + extension;
    }
}
```

Now, where would I specify that which function I want to call for http get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should separate the two method from each other using annotation path

```
@Path("/SignIn")
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public String SignIn(@QueryParam("username") String username, @QueryParam("password") String password, @QueryParam("extension") String extension) {

    //TODO return proper representation object
    return "Credentials  " + username + " : " + password + " : " + extension;
}
```

and @Path("/SignOut")  for other method like above.

Then call proper method to sign in or out for a user.

Comment: I have defined a path before the class i.e. @Path("generic"), do I have to remove it ? as I am getting an internal server error now.

Comment: should be careful with this approach, since `/signin` is not a "resource" it is a "verb"/"action", which does is not very much in accordance with REST principles... furthermore `GET` should not be used in this situation but `POST`, given that this call will make "changes" on a resource (user authentication).

Comment: I would have used POST but seems like I have no other option but GET because of some restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

Sign-in/out should be carefully handled, i.e., make sure you use the right channel security (e.g.: SSL) and authentication mechanisms - take a look into security frameworks (e.g.: Apache Shiro, Spring Security, etc.).

Coming to your question (and abstracting from any issues related with handling security/authentication), you could have a "base" resource "users", on top of which you build several URIs for different "user resources". For example you could define a user resource called "loginstatus":

- `/users/{username}/loginstatus` - this resource would allow to specify/retrieve the current user "login status"

To define sign-in or sign-out "action", you could use (in this approach) "query parameters":

- `POST /users/{username}/loginstatus?action=login&password=userPassword`
- `POST /users/{username}/loginstatus?action=logout&password=userPassword`

So, basically we create a "resource" called "loginstatus", which allows to perform the different operations over it... You should not have a resource called "sign-in", that is an "action" or "verb". A `POST` should be used to sign-in/out not `GET`, since you are not only retrieving a resource, you are actually making a change on the resource (sign-in or sign-out, which changes the user "loginstatus" resource - normally an entry in the User authentication DB).

You can implement this by having something like this:

```
@Path("/users")
public class GenericResource {

    @POST
    @Path{/{username}/loginstatus
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String SignIn(@PathParam("username") String username, 
          @QueryParam("password") String password, 
          @QueryParam("action") String action) {

       // if action = "login" => perform login
       // if action = "logout" => perform logout
    }

}
```

Comment: thanx emgsilva for guidance.